# How can I get Bitdefender (antivirus) to scan a file and delete it if the file contains a virus?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, antivirus, appdata

This is the code I use to write my file to the app_data folder:

```
var filename = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data") + "/" thefilename;
var ms = new MemoryStream();

file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
file.InputStream.Position = 0;
byte[] contents = ms.ToArray();

var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create,
System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fileStream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);

fileStream.Close();
```

This writes the file fine. However, if there is a virus on it, Bitdefender does not delete this file, unless I go on the IIS and manually try to open/move the file. If I do that, then it is instantly deleted.

If I copy and paste the test virus file into the app_data folder directly then Bitdefender removes it instantly.

I have tried to use various ways to read/move the file with `System.IO.File.Move`/`Open`/`ReadAllLines`. Yet, nothing triggers bit defender to remove the file.

The only thing I got to work was creating a new process to open the file. However, I don't want to be doing that on the server.  I am looking for a different solution. This is the code that I've used to open the file, which does cause Bitdefender to scan and remove the infected file:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
cmd.Start();
```

A solution with `System.IO.File.Open` would be best for me in this situation, but I cannot figure out why it isn't working. Alternately, a way to trigger Bitdefender to instantly scan the file would also be a viable solution.

Comment: It's not working because BitDefender doesn't have hooks into the IIS process. It does, however, have hooks into the native Windows code that starts a process. But I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve here - a file containing a virus isn't inherently dangerous unless someone tries to execute it, which any antivirus will already catch. This feels like an X-Y problem - what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to detect and stop viruses from being uploaded to his server

Comment: @IanKemp my application lets users upload files so I upload them to app_data first to check for viruses and then store them elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the issue with the help of @sheavens and following code:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Bitdefender\Endpoint Security\product.console.exe";
var args = String.Format("/c FileScan.OnDemand.RunScanTask custom path=\"{0}\" infectedAction1=delete", filename);
startInfo.Arguments = args;
cmd.StartInfo = startInfo;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
var result = cmd.Start();
```

This creates a new process and looks up the bitdefender exe, and then runs a command to scan the file at the provided path.

Comment: it is possible to scan file befere I store it? I mean to scan e.g. file stream?

Comment: This was posted over a year ago and I remember this being the only solution that worked. So to answer your question, no I don't think it's possible. But if you find a way post it here! :)

Comment: @sicknote I see you are using Endpoint Security. Does the free version have command line support?

Comment: @Joshua Unfortunately not :( I used a free trial and then had to pay